# R- Custom Keras Layer With Weight Constraints

Tags: r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to write a custom Keras layer with trainable weights in R which:

- Takes an input vector x and returns the value `exp(A * X*A)` where $A$ is diagonal and trainable..

Where *exp* is the matrix exponential map.

Comment: What do you mean?  This is what R returns to me

Comment: @DanielMöller  Sorry I'm really new at time so I don't understand the issue

Comment: Is `*` a matrix multiplication or an elementwise multiplication?

Comment: Can you please describe the dimensions of A and X, with batch size included?

Comment: Its a matrix multiplication and both A and X are square d x d matrices (d>0 an integer).

Comment: Ok, where is the batch size in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that it's very important that you understand where your batch size is, and that a layer CANNOT have weights with sizes based on the batch size (unless you define your inputs with `batch_shape` or `batch_input_shape` instead of `shape` -- this will force you to use a fixed batch size in the model). Since the batch size is usually for "individual" and "independent" samples, it's not healthy to use the batch size in operations and mixing samples!

That said, I am assuming that `X` here has shape `(batch, dim, dim)`, and that `A` will have shape `(dim, dim)` consequently.

For this, you build a custom layer such as here: https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/guide/keras/custom_layers/

Where `build` will have `kernel` (`A`) with shape `(1, dim, 1)` --

```
    build = function(input_shape) {
      self$kernel <- self$add_weight(
        name = 'kernel', 
        shape = list(1,input_shape[[2]], 1),
        initializer = initializer_random_normal(), #you may choose different initializers
        trainable = TRUE
      )
    },
```

And call will use a mathematical trick to simulate the diagonal.

Notice that if `A` is diagonal, the result of `A x X x A` will be `B*X` (elementwise), where `B` is:

```
#supposing A has the elements [a, b, c, ...] in the diagonals,

B is:
[ [aa, ab, ac, ...],
  [ab, bb, bc, ...],
  [ac, bc, cc, ...],
  ...
]
```

Because of this, we will not use diagonals, but a broadcasting trick with elementwise multiplication:

```
    call = function(x, mask = NULL) {
      kernelTransposed <- tf$reshape(self$kernel, shape(1L, 1L, -1L)) #(1, 1, dim)
      B <- self$kernel * kernelTransposed #(1, dim, dim)
      tf$math$exp(x * B)
    },
```

The output shape goes unchanged:

```
    compute_output_shape = function(input_shape) {
      input_shape
    }
```

Comment: I'm abit confused where exactly is the function (matrix) exponential exp?

Comment: @AIM_BLB, sorry, I forgot the exp, it's in the answer now.

Comment: Out of curiosity.  If I didn't want A how would things simplify (trying to get my mind around this...)

Comment: I don't understand the question.... only the exp? Use a `Lambda` layer with a function that calls only the exp.

Comment: I just noticed (unless I'm mistaken) the function you use in the layer is not an *matrix* exponential but an element-wise exponential

Comment: Ah, that's why it was giving me interesting readouts.
Its defined through the Taylor series (like in the univariate sense) and there's a tensorflow function:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/expm

but I don't think there's a Keras version :/

Comment: You don't need it to be "keras". Keras is totally build "on top of" tensorflow, so you can just go with `tf$linalg$expm`, just as I used `tf$math$exp`.

Comment: oh really?  Fantastic!  I didn't know I can do that kinda thing in R.
I assume all I have to do is library("tensorflow") then im good to go?  Thanks so much Daniel!

Comment: I don't use R, but it looks like that's it: https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorials/advanced/customization/tensors-operations/