# Adding Bidirectional in a Keras LSTM results in a RuntimeError('You must compile your model before using it.')

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm doing:

```py
self.model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm1_size, input_shape=(
        seq_length, feature_dim), return_sequences=True)))
self.model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm2_size, return_sequences=True)))
self.model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm3_size, return_sequences=True)))
self.model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm4_size, return_sequences=True)))
self.model.add(Dense(feature_dim, activation='relu'))
```

and I get the error:

```
RuntimeError('You must compile your model before using it.')
```

However, when I do the same thing without the `Bidirectional`, it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `compile`?

Comment: Yes - I call `compile` before `fit_generator`

Comment: Cool, this might be a recent bug? You're not the first person with this exact problem today.... but the other one was using R.

Comment: Can you link me to the other problem you found? Maybe I can figure something out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60281789/r-custom-keras-layer-with-weight-constraints?noredirect=1#comment106656524_60281789

Comment: Hey consider using the functional api instead of sequential. I've had some occasions when this error popped erroneously while using sequential, and they disappeared solely by switching to functional.

Comment: Can you clarify how that would be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like a bug in your case because I tried the same its working normally.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Bidirectional

lstm1_size = 4
seq_length = 2
lstm2_size = 4
feature_dim = 1
lstm3_size = 4
lstm4_size = 4
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm1_size, input_shape=(
        seq_length, feature_dim), return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm2_size, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm3_size, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm4_size, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(feature_dim, activation='relu'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

please check if model is compiled within/outside class?
if problem is solved already, please let us know as well.